# Laravel HasMany create child record

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a problem when I'm trying to create a child model associated to his parent.

I have 2 models:

- Instituion (has many addresses)
- Address (has 1 Institution)

When I click a Institution and I go to show.blade.php where I have a form to create an Address for that Institution I can't get from the request the field "instituion_id" which relates child with parent.

This is shown in the request:

Request Data

[image]

From the form I'm calling the following route: action="/institution/{{ $institution->id }}/addresses"

This is the code in AddressController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request->all());
    Address::create($request->all());
    return back();
}
```

When I test it, the DB is asking for the isntitution_id column:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'institution_id' doesn't
>   have a default value (SQL: insert into `addresses` (`address_name`,
>   `address_number`, `address_full_name`, `address_city`,
>   `address_state`, `address_postal_code`, `address_country`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (a, a, a, a, a, a, a, 2017-12-14
>   14:06:47, 2017-12-14 14:06:47))

So, how to I pass from the form the field "institution_id" and how do I get it in the controller and assocuiated to the child record?

I read many posts but in all of them they are just create a child record with one field but I want to process the complere request with all Addres fields.

Regards

Comment: You can have a hidden field in the form in your HTML with ´institution_id´ and set the value to be the one for the institution. Hope you have access control for who can create addresses before you get to this code

Comment: Just make sure you have the $institution object available in your show.blade.php view.

Comment: Thanks @rypskar I tried that but it's returning the field with null

Comment: Thanks @robbyrr the object is in the form because Im listing the instituion but I can't get the ID value in a hidden field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it. I had 2 models/controllers: website and visitor. Visitor is dependent on website.

Routes:

```
Route::resource('website', 'WebsiteController');
Route::resource('website/{website}/visitor', 'VisitorController');
```

Don't forget to set all the relationships. I'll only show you the one that I'll use to save the data, in the Website model:

```
public function visitors()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Visitor');
}
```

Then, in the store inside the VisitorController:

```
public function store(Request $request, Website $website)
{
    return response()->json(
        $website->visitors()->create([
            ... fields without website_id (the relationship field) ...
        ]), 
        201
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access the id from the parameters of the `store` method like this :

In the routes file :

```
Route::post('/institution/{institution_id}/addresses', 'YourController@store')
```

In the controller :

```
public function store($institution_id, Request $request)
{
    $request->request->add(['institution_id' => $institution_id]);
    // dd($request->all());
    Address::create($request->all());
    return back();
}
```

Ps : Don't forget to add `institution_id` to the fillable fields in the Address Model.

Comment: Thanks @maraboc, that worked, but it's the correct way to do it? Regards

Comment: About the parameter yes it is, that is the recommanded way because if you add the hidden field you will just duplicate the information

Comment: Thanks @Maraboc !!

Answer (score 3):

If all relationships are set, the documentation has what you're looking for
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method
Example:

```
// Routes (If laravel version > 5.2 web.php I guess
Route::post('/institution/{institution_id}/addresses', 'Controller@store')

// app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $institution = Institution::find($request->institution_id);
    $address = $institution->addresses()->create($request->all());
    return back();
}
// app/Institution.php
class Institution extends Model
{
    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Address', 'institution_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I read that documentation but always gives me the following error: Call to a member function addresses() on null

Comment: As i said, if your model has the relationships set https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Yes it has both relationships

Comment: Have you changed the route as it is in my answer?

Comment: Yes I changed too

Comment: Please run this in the project root folder `php artisan route:cache`. If even after this `$request->institution_id` is null check if the link has the correct ID there

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I made all the changes again and executed the route:cache and same error.

Comment: It looks strange for me the solution provided by @Maraboc although is working because it's adding a value to the array and not using the entire request (which doesnt has de institution_id but it's in the show.blade template file)

Answer (score 0):

```
$p=Parent::find($anId);
$ch=Child::create(['somekey0'=>value0,'somekey1'=>value1,
...,'somekeyN'=>valueN]);
$ch->my_parent()->associate($p);
$ch->save();
```